# Google analytics 4 tags in google tag manager not firing on live

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I am using google tag manager to fire some GA4 events in parallel to existing UA events. But the GA4 events only seems to work in preview mode and not on live. While UA events are being fired in preview as well live.

I have GA4 configuration tag.

[image]

Which should get triggered everytime a cmpEvent is triggered.

[image]

I can see the events getting triggered in preview mode

[image]

But it does not get triggered on live website. I have already ruled out the usual suspects of not published gtm container etc.

Can anyone tell me, what might be wrong here. Does google analytics 4 require any special consent that i am missing.

Comment: Whatever is populating the cmpConsentVendors, is this doing the same thing for both preview and live? Are the values the same? What is the debug panel showing for live?

Comment: I can tell you for sure, that cmpConsentVendors is ,s26, for preview and live

Comment: Can you post what the PROD's Tag Details is? What is the firing condition that isn't being met?

Comment: As far as i understood the cmpConsentVendor needs to be s26 for UA configuration to load. I can see the configuration loading in preview and PROD. Now i assume the same for GA4, as i did not find any documentation pointing otherwise. I put the condition cmpConsentVendor to be s26 for GA4 to configuration to load as seen in screenshot nr. 2. Now this condition is met in preview mode and it shows the configuration as loaded as seen in screenshot nr. 3. But this should trigger a pageView event, which is not happening. The debugMode in Google analytics is showing no event.

Comment: Also the confugration is not being loaded on live. So i have two problems. No pageView event being sent to analytics and no configuration being loaded in live.

Comment: I would assume if the config isn't firing, then that is why your pageView event isn't working. d

Comment: @AnimeshSharma did you find any solution to the above? I'm Facing same issue

Comment: Hello @NoumanAhmad, I found the problem that, my data layer was being reseted by an (old line of code) after being initialised by gtm. I fixed it by moving the gtm data layer initialisation below the old line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, clearing my browser cookies and history for some reason allowed the GA4 tags to appear in the preview debugger.

I also previewed the version in which the GA4 tags were first published.